# Adding issue to GitHub, what is etiquette

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I'm new to GitHub, and am interested in someone's code. However, there is error, and I'd like to add issue, but I'm wondering if I should try to contact the person first (I don't know him, I saw his blog on something quite useful)

When I try googling GitHub etiquette, it refers to [someone who owns the repository](http://www.defmacro.org/2013/04/03/issue-etiquette.html) and has to address issues in a timely manner.

Thank you

Comment: I'm puzzled if I should be tagging this as off-topic since it doesn't seem related to programming in any way, but I'll still give out an answer.

Comment: @bitoiu Can you tell me the proper forum to post in, for future reference

Comment: I'm not sure honestly, that's why I didn't flag the question. Maybe someone else will suggest another stack-exchange channel or simply confirm that the question belongs here.

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening an issue as and tagging it as a question (for example) is much more useful and productive that sending an e-mail or contacting the repository maintainers directly.

Next time someone finds the same error or query, they will potentially also find a solution linked to the issue that you are going to created.

In terms of ettiquete GitHub has a great post on [how to create pull-requests](https://github.com/blog/1943-how-to-write-the-perfect-pull-request) from which you might take some hints, but to be honest if you follow the guidelines from StackOverflow on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) they will in my opinion be good tips for whatever site you are targeting.

If it's a runtime or compilation (programming) error:

> Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

If it's a question try to separate the goal that you are trying to achieve from the solution you've adopted that led to the error, at least that's what I try to do.